# Creating custom rails route: undefined method `+@' for "10":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am making a custom rails route as:

`match '/setFavoriteRestaurant/:user_id/:restaurant_id/:campaignSetFav_id/:metro_id/:time_period', to: 'requests#setFavoriteRestaurant', via: 'get'`

with controller action:

```
def setFavoriteRestaurant
        setFavorite = "INSERT INTO androidchatterdatabase.users_favorite_restaurants(usersId,restaurantId,campaignIdSetFav,metroId,timePeriod,favoritedDt)
                       VALUES(" + params[:user_id].to_s + "," 
                                + params[:restaurant_id].to_s + "," 
                                + params[:campaignSetFav_id].to_s + ","
                                + params[:metro_id].to_s + ","
                                + params[:time_period].to_s + ",
                                NOW());"

        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(setFavorite)
    end
```

Yet when testing in the browser with: `http://localhost:3000/setFavoriteRestaurant/1/2/3/5/4`

it returns an odd error as: `undefined method +@' for "2":String`

Why is this the case when other methods, setup exactly the same are fine to run?

Comment: Any reason why you're executing raw SQL instead of using Rails?

Comment: For this purpose, I prefer to use raw SQL

Comment: As long as you're happy about being wide open to sql injection...

Comment: @FrederickCheung, Yes it is at present, but it is just a prototype to get the ball rolling. Of course, prior to production release we will "batten down the hatches" and secure the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how you broke up the lines. Ruby doesn't know that the `VALUES(" +` line and the `+ params[:restaurant_id]` are part of the same thing. This is because the `VALUES( +` line is complete. Move the `+` to the end of the line so that Ruby will know to expect the next line to be a continuation.

```
setFavorite = "INSERT INTO androidchatterdatabase.users_favorite_restaurants(usersId,restaurantId,campaignIdSetFav,metroId,timePeriod,favoritedDt)" + 
                      "VALUES(" + params[:user_id].to_s + "," +
                      params[:restaurant_id].to_s + "," +
                      params[:campaignSetFav_id].to_s + "," +
                      params[:metro_id].to_s + "," +
                      params[:time_period].to_s + ",NOW());"
```

Also, note that I moved some other things around to avoid new lines and extra spaces.

I'm not sure why you prefer raw SQL here, but you should consider going through Rails. Seems like you're opening yourself up to SQL injection. At the very least, you could have some constraints in the route to match only integers.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a couple of ways to quote multi line strings:

1) Here it is with ruby's heredoc syntax:

```
def some_action

  setFavorite = <<-"END_OF_INSERT"
    INSERT INTO androidchatterdatabase.users_favorite_restaurants(
      usersId,
      restaurantId,
      campaignIdSetFav,
      metroId,
      timePeriod,
      favoritedDt
    )
    VALUES( 
      "#{params[:user_id]}",  
      "#{params[:restaurant_id]}",
      "#{params[:campaignSetFav_id]}",
      "#{params[:metro_id]}",
      "#{params[:time_period]}",
      NOW()
    );
  END_OF_INSERT

end
```

Explanation:

```
setFavorite = <<-"END_OF_INSERT"

-   =>  Terminator does not have to be at the start of the line.
""  =>  This is a double quoted string--do interpolation.
```

2) Here it is with `%Q{}`:

```
  setFavorite = %Q{
    INSERT INTO androidchatterdatabase.users_favorite_restaurants(
      usersId,
      restaurantId,
      campaignIdSetFav,
      metroId,
      timePeriod,
      favoritedDt
    )
    VALUES( 
      "#{params[:user_id]}",  
      "#{params[:restaurant_id]}",
      "#{params[:campaignSetFav_id]}",
      "#{params[:metro_id]}",
      "#{params[:time_period]}",
      NOW()
    );
  }
```

However, your SQL statement is still vulnerable to sql injection attacks.  Check your db adapter for how to do parameter substitutions.